# Bokeh CheckboxGroup not updating boxplots in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter, bokeh, boxplot, interactive

I’m trying to create interactive boxplots using Bokeh and Jupyter Notebook. I have a CheckboxGroup for each factor and I want the boxplots to update when one or several checkboxes are selected. However, when I select one or several checkboxes, nothing happens and the boxplots do not update.

I'm a relatively total beginner, so any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Below, the full code:

```
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show
from bokeh.layouts import gridplot
from bokeh.layouts import column as bokeh_column
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, CheckboxGroup
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.transform import factor_cmap
import pandas as pd

output_notebook()

# Load the data from the CSV file into a DataFrame
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

# Convert non-numeric values in the 'Value' column to NaN
df['Value'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Value'], errors='coerce')

# Remove rows containing NaN values in the 'Value' column
df = df.dropna(subset=['Value'])

# Remove invalid characters from color codes
for column in df.columns:
    if 'Color' in column:
        df[column] = df[column].str.replace('\xa0', '')

# Define factors for categorical data
factors = ['Factor1', 'Factor2', 'Factor3', 'Factor4', 'Factor5']

# Specify the desired order of the values for each factor
orders = {
    'Factor1': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'],
    'Factor2': ['K', 'L', 'M', 'N'],
    'Factor3': ['O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W'],
    'Factor4': ['X', 'Y', 'Z', 'AA'],
    'Factor5': ['AB', 'AC', 'AD', 'AE', 'AF',
                'AG', 'AH', 'AI', 'AJ']
}

boxplots = []
sources = []

for factor in factors:
    # Create a new DataFrame with the grouped data
    grouped = df.groupby(factor).agg({'Value': ['min', 'max', 'mean', 'median']})
    grouped.columns = ['min', 'max', 'mean', 'median']

    # Reorder the grouped DataFrame according to the specified order
    grouped = grouped.loc[orders[factor]]

    # Create a ColumnDataSource from the grouped DataFrame
    source_grouped = ColumnDataSource(grouped)
    sources.append(source_grouped)

    # Create boxplot with y-axis set to log scale
    boxplot = figure(title=factor, x_range=list(grouped.index), plot_width=500, plot_height=200, y_axis_type='log')
    boxplot.segment(x0=factor, y0='min', x1=factor, y1='max', source=source_grouped)
    boxplot.vbar(x=factor, top='median', bottom='min', width=0.5, source=source_grouped,
                 fill_color=factor_cmap(factor, list(df[f'{factor}Color'].dropna()), list(df[factor].dropna())))
    boxplot.vbar(x=factor, top='max', bottom='median', width=0.5, source=source_grouped,
                 fill_color=factor_cmap(factor, list(df[f'{factor}Color'].dropna()), list(df[factor].dropna())))

    boxplots.append(boxplot)

grid = gridplot(boxplots, ncols=2)

# Create a CheckboxGroup for each factor
checkbox_groups = {}
for factor in factors:
    checkbox_group = CheckboxGroup(labels=orders[factor], active=list(range(len(orders[factor]))))
    checkbox_groups[factor] = checkbox_group

def update(attr, old, new):
    try:
        # Filter the DataFrame based on the selected values for each factor
        filtered_df = df.copy()
        for factor in factors:
            checkbox_group = checkbox_groups[factor]
            selected_values = [checkbox_group.labels[i] for i in checkbox_group.active]
            filtered_df = filtered_df[filtered_df[factor].isin(selected_values)]

        # Update the data sources of the boxplots with the filtered data
        for i, factor in enumerate(factors):
            source_grouped = sources[i]
            grouped = filtered_df.groupby(factor).agg({'Value': ['min', 'max', 'mean', 'median']})
            grouped.columns = ['min', 'max', 'mean', 'median']
            if not grouped.empty:
                grouped = grouped.loc[orders[factor]]
            new_data = ColumnDataSource(grouped).data
            source_grouped.data.update(new_data)
            
# Add the callback function to each CheckboxGroup
for factor in factors:
    checkbox_group = checkbox_groups[factor]
    checkbox_group.on_change('active', update)

layout = bokeh_column(grid, *checkbox_groups.values())
show(layout)
```

Comment: Can you link to the CSV file or provide a toy example that is a complete and minimal reproducible example as spelled out under 'Help others reproduce the problem' in [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)? Also, please update your post to include if other interactive Bokeh examples work and update in the environment you are working in, such as in the same notebook?